# Accessing API-endpoint is not possible?

Tags: python, api, post, python-requests

i try to use this API-endpoint using python request: https://api.bigparser.com/api-endpoints/#get-grid-search

I tried it with the following code:

```
queryTableURL = f"https://www.bigparser.com/api/v2/grid/{gridID}/search"
queryTableRequest = {}
requestHeaders = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'authId': authId}
response = requests.post(queryTableURL, headers=requestHeaders)
# response = requests.post(queryTableURL, data=json.dumps(queryTableRequest), headers=requestHeaders)
responseData = json.loads(response.text)
print(responseData)
```

But i only get this output:
{'errorMessage': 'System error. Please contact admin.', 'otherDetails': {}, 'errorType': 'SYSTEMERROR', 'recoverable': False}

I tried it with both requests.posts above - one time with that one in the the line4 and also with the currently uncommented in line5 - both with the same error from above.

What i am doing wrong? How can i use this API-endpoint?

Comment: Have you tried without setting the content-type? I don't see any requirement setting that, and you're also not passing any content in the first variant anyway.

Comment: What is `response.status_code`? 500?

Comment: Also, try using a GET method instead. I know it says that the HTTP method should be POST, but perhaps that's a mistake (though all the search methods are listed as being POST. Odd choice, but that's apparently how it is).

Comment: Yes the status-code is 500
I tried without the content-type and only with: requestHeaders = {'authId': authId} => same result
And i also tried it with GET instead of PSOT with: response = requests.get(queryTableURL, headers=requestHeaders) => same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code it was finally working:

```
queryTableURL = f"https://www.bigparser.com/api/v2/grid/{gridID}/search"
queryTableRequest = {"query": {"pagination": {
                                  "startRow": 1,
                                  "rowCount": 500
                                },
                              }}
requestHeaders = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'authId': authId}
response = requests.post(queryTableURL, data=json.dumps(queryTableRequest), headers=requestHeaders)
responseData = json.loads(response.text)
print(response.status_code)
print(responseData["totalRowCount"])
```